# How can I show a private picture from SharePoint in my Teams Chatbot based on Azure QnAMaker?

Tags: azure, microsoft-teams, azure-qna-maker

I am trying to make a chatbot that will be channeled to Teams using the Azure QnA Maker/ MS botframework. I would like to use pictures in some of my Q&A's that are stored in a SharePoint folder.

As a test I have added a Q&A with the same picture twice: once from private SP and once from the internet.The account I use has access to the said SharePoint and I can add both pictures just fine in the qnamaker.ai portal with the markdown below.(It also works fine in the test mode of the portal itself)

```
SP\n\n![SP](**link of SP website**/Shared%20Documents/squirrel.jpg)\n\nInternet\n\n![pic1](https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507666405895-422eee7d517f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80)
```

My QnA Maker is currently channeled to Teams, and that is where the problem happens; the private picture seems inaccessible. I am accessing Teams from an account that also as access to the SharePoint.
[QnAMakerTeamsIssue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTb0E.png)

How can I make my Teams app read the private SharePoint image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Teams actually caches the images in it's own CDN, so it needs to "pre-fetch" them, so to speak. As a result, it needs to have public anonymous access to the content. This is not possible by default with SharePoint, so you'd need to:

1. put the content somewhere else
2. I haven't tested this, but it might be possible to utilise the CDN capabilities of SharePoint. It needs admin control, but perhaps there's a one-off location you could use for this. See more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/use-microsoft-365-cdn-with-spo?view=o365-worldwide)

Update: I did more research, but unfortunately the SharePoint CDN can't be used for this as it is configured to only accept requests from SharePoint pages themselves (i.e. the content can't be *used* outside of SharePoint). I created a [uservoice request for this](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/41548216-allow-sharepoint-to-accept-requests-from-teams-ei), in case others want to up-vote it.

Comment: Even though SO said to avoid comments such as "thanks", thank you so much for your efforts! I was just about to ask my boss for admin privileges' to try CDN but I guess that won't be necessary anymore. I know MS ignores most uservoice requests, but my fingers are crossed!

Comment: thanks for the "thanks" and glad to help! Just to be clear on this - I did the _research_ online, and found that as an answer from MS, but I also physically did the testing on a test tenancy, to verify - it's definitely as per this.